# How to change paths of img sources

Tags: php

switch.php

```
<img class='imgR' src='../img/gold_01.png' alt='img'>
<img class='imgR' src='../img/gold_02.png' alt='img'>
```

I want to include this file `(include ('switch.php')` but all `src` paths should be changed from `../img` to `img/`

I cannot do this using jquery, because images are not loaded at all with the wrong `src` attribute.

So, probably they should be changed before `include()` function, i.e. using php

Any help?

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit better? Why can't you just output the correct image path from the server side code? Could you either use a path which is relative to the root of the site (ie. prefix with "/") or have a variable which contains the relative location?

Comment: The problem is not understandable.

Comment: @mit, that's because I need this file with original `src` attributes on other places. I don't want to duplicate this file just because of different img sources. In fact the sources are the same, but the paths are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in foo.php

```
$siteRoot = '.';
include('switch.php');
```

in bar/foo.php

```
$siteRoot = '..';
include('../switch.php');
```

in switch.php

```
<img class='imgR' src='<?php echo $siteRoot; ?>/img/gold_01.png' alt='img'>
<img class='imgR' src='<?php echo $siteRoot; ?>/img/gold_02.png' alt='img'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In php:

```
$var = "<img class='imgR' src='../img/gold_01.png' alt='img'>"
    . "<img class='imgR' src='../img/gold_02.png' alt='img'>";

echo preg_replace('/src=\'\.\.\/img\/([^\']+)\'/','src=\'img/$1\'' ,$var); 

//outputs:
//<img class=​"imgR" src=​"img/gold_01.png" alt=​"img">​
//<img class=​"imgR" src=​"img/​gold_02.png" alt=​"img">​
```

If you run your whole HTML page through this replacing function, I think you'll get what you want.